# Finder Sync: Sender passed to action is different instance of NSMenuItem

Tags: macos, finder, nsmenuitem, findersync

I have implemented a Finder Sync extension according to the provided sample given from Apple.

After clicking on the newly created contextual menu item the according action `sampleAction` is executed. Unfortunately the sender passed to the method does not match the instance created in `menuForMenuKind`.

The code

```
- (NSMenu *)menuForMenuKind:(FIMenuKind)whichMenu
{
    NSMenuItem* menuItem = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"testTitle" action:@selector(sampleAction:) keyEquivalent:@""];
    menuItem.tag = 1;

    // print menu attributes
    NSLog(@"------------------original menu-----------------");
    NSLog(@"menu address: %p", menuItem);
    NSLog(@"menu tag: %ld", menuItem.tag);
    NSLog(@"menu title: '%@'", menuItem.title);

    NSMenu *menu = [[NSMenu alloc] initWithTitle:@""];
    [menu addItem:menuItem];

    return menu;
}

- (IBAction)sampleAction:(id)sender
{
    if( [sender isKindOfClass:[NSMenuItem class]])
    {
        NSMenuItem* menuItem = sender;

        NSLog(@"------------------menu passed to action-----------------");
        NSLog(@"menu address: %p", menuItem);
        NSLog(@"menu tag: %ld", menuItem.tag);
        NSLog(@"menu title: '%@'", menuItem.title);
    }
}
```

results in the following output after I clicked on the element in the context menu

```
2014-12-07 19:55:36.923 FinderSync Extension[1265:62630] ------------------original menu----------------
2014-12-07 19:55:36.923 FinderSync Extension[1265:62630] menu address: 0x6080000abbe0
2014-12-07 19:55:36.924 FinderSync Extension[1265:62630] menu tag: 1
2014-12-07 19:55:36.924 FinderSync Extension[1265:62630] menu title: 'testTitle'
2014-12-07 19:55:40.328 FinderSync Extension[1265:62630] ------------------menu passed to action----------------
2014-12-07 19:55:40.328 FinderSync Extension[1265:62630] menu address: 0x6080000aba00
2014-12-07 19:55:40.328 FinderSync Extension[1265:62630] menu tag: 0
2014-12-07 19:55:40.328 FinderSync Extension[1265:62630] menu title: ''
```

.

Is there any chance to link the sender to the menu item, which was clicked on?

Comment: Do you have any solution for this?

Comment: Not yet, unfortunately :(

Comment: hmm let Apple know about your needs using the Apple bug reporting system. Now i am using different selector for different menu items.

Answer (score 8):

For reference, this is apparently intended behavior. I filed a bug report with Apple, and this was their response:

> This issue behaves as intended based on the following:
>
> Finder Sync does not keep around the specific NSMenuItem* instances, and very few properties are respected (only title, action, image, and enabled). In a future release, the -tag property is likely to be supported, but not -representedObject. — If you require a dynamic set of actions, it should be possible to use functions such as sel_registerName and method_setImplementation (in ) to create methods at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

The `FIFinderSyncController` / `FIFinderSyncProtocol` docs offer the best documentation for these menus and methods that I can find.

> `menu(for menu: FIMenuKind)`
>
> Specific menu item properties are used: title, action, image, and enabled.
>
> Starting in 10.11: tag, state, and indentationLevel also work, and submenus are allowed.

The `tag` property that was not persisted when you asked this question is now persisted in macOS 10.11+.

The `representedObject` property is **not** persisted by the time we get the callback, which would be extremely useful. The NSMenuItem object is different by that point as well.

It's not ideal, but the now-persisted (and invisible to the user) `tag` field should be enough to pass information from menu creation and action callback.